# How to use js to dynamically add components and listen to their events in vue3？

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've recently been learning Vue3. I want to add components dynamically, and the parent component can listen to the events of the added chirld components. To make it clear what I want to do, I have written the following code. I want a new button to be added when the mouse moves over any of the buttons. But only the first button actually triggers the hello function, which means that the code `"v-on:addButton": hello` in line 7 of `App.vue` doesn't work. I would like to know how to modify the code to meet my requirements, or if there is another easy way to implement this functionality.

Chirld `components/Hello.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  defineProps(['text'])
  defineEmits(['addButton'])
</script>

<template>
  <button @mouseenter="$emit('addButton')">{{text}}</button>
</template>
```

Father `App.vue`

```
<script setup>
  import {createApp} from 'vue'
  import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
    
  let cnt = 0
  function hello() {
    console.log('you enter a button')
    const app = createApp(Hello, {"text": String(cnt++), "v-on:addButton": hello})
    const newNode = document.createElement('div')
    document.getElementById("rootDiv").append(newNode)
    app.mount(newNode)
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div id="rootDiv">
    <Hello text="0" v-on:addButton="hello"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Update:**

Thanks for the replies. I found that simply changing `"v-on:addButton": hello` to `onaddButton: hello` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the DOM directly in most cases doesn't work with Vue since you'll loose the reactivity and other binding stuff, another approach is to use `cnt` variable to render the components using `v-for` directive ;:

```html
<script setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
  
  let cnt = ref(0)
  function addBtn() {
     cnt.value++
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div id="rootDiv">
    <Hello v-for="i in cnt" :text="i" v-on:addButton="addBtn"/>
  </div>
</template>
```